# How to upsert nested objects with dynamic properties in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-query

I have a document in elasticsearch that looks like this:

```
{
    "_index": "stats",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "publishTime": {
            "lastUpdate": 1580991095131,
            "h0_4": 0,
            "h4_8": 0,
            "h8_12": 3,
            "h12_16": 5,
            "h16_20": 2,
            "h20_24": 1
        },
        "postCategories": {
             "lastUpdate": 1580991095131,
             "tech": 56,
             "lifestyle": 63,
             "healthcare": 49,
             "finances": 25,
         }
     }
 }
```

Updating/Incrementing existing property values by sending a `POST` request to `/stats/_update/1` works great! However, if I try to upsert a non-existing property name under `postCategories`, I get a `Bad Request (400)` error of type `remote_transport_exception/illegal_argument_exception`:

```
"ctx._source.postCategories.relationships += params.postCategories.relationships",
                                                                  ^---- HERE"
```

**Upsert**

```
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.postCategories.relationships += params.postCategories.relationships",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
            "postCategories": {
                "relationships": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "upsert": {
       "postCategories": {
            "relationships": 2
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried the Scripted Upsert method by following the documentation from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts), however, the same error occurs:

**Scripted Upsert**

```
{
    "scripted_upsert":true,
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.postCategories.relationships += params.postCategories.relationships",
        "params": {
            "postCategories": {
                "relationships": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "upsert": {}
}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I properly add/upsert new property names under `postCategories` object, please?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its basically saying that you are trying to assign a value to a field that doesnt exist. I think below should work(not tested).

Try to check if field exists - continue with operation if it exists. 
Else add new field and assign value.

```
"if (ctx._source.postCategories.containsKey(\"relationships\")) { ctx._source.postCategories.relationships += params.postCategories.relationships} else { ctx._source.postCategories[\"relationships\"] = params.postCategories.relationships}",
```